# SQL Server stored procedure convert varbinary to Base64String

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have been tasked to create a stored procedure which can look at a table and pull up the `ObjectGUID` and `extensionAttribute6` column and do a compare.

Basically the `objectGUID` is a `varbinary` column and `extensionAttribute6` is a `nvarchar` column. What I really need to do is pull up all records where `extensionAttribute6` is not null, then take the value of `objectGUID` and convert it to a base-64 string value and compare that value with value in the column `extensionAttribute6` of that record. If the value match, then insert a calculated column called `Compliance` (`nvarchar(10)`) and put `True` there, else put false there.

[image]

Comment: SQL Server/Oracle/MySQL?

Comment: Sorry its MS MSql 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `XML` to get `Base64`:

Getting records that `decoded(objectGUID)` = `extensionAttribute6`

```
SELECT *
FROM your_tab
WHERE extensionAttribute6 IS NOT NULL
  AND CAST(CAST('' as XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("objectGUID"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) = extensionAttribute6
```

And update:

```
UPDATE your_tab
SET Compliance = IIF(CAST(CAST('' as XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("objectGUID"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) = extensionAttribute6, 'True', 'False')
```

For storing `True/False` you should use `BIT` datatype instead of string.

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT *
   [Compliance] = IIF(CAST(CAST('' as XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("objectGUID"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) = extensionAttribute6, 'True', 'False')
FROM your_tab
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. When I run the first part, it gives me the output and I can see what the base64value will look like. But I don't actually want to modify the table. I just want to see which rows have extensionAttribute6 values which have valid base64 value for that row's objectGUID.

Comment: Lad2025 - Thank you. This is super and this worked like a charm. Really appreciate your quick response and expert guidance :)